# How to check SQL Server version

Tags: sql-server-2008, version

What are the possible ways to determine the deployed SQL Server version?

I’ve tried to do it using the SQL Server software. I want to do it using a command line SQL statement.

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1140/how-to-tell-what-sql-server-version-you-are-running/

Comment: https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/how-to-check-sql-server-version/

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Following are possible ways to see the version:

**Method 1:** Connect to the instance of SQL Server, and then run the following query:

```
Select @@version
```

An example of the output of this query is as follows:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)   Mar 29 2009 
10:11:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express 
Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: )
```

**Method 2:** Connect to the server by using Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio. After Object Explorer is connected, it will show the version information in parentheses, together with the user name that is used to connect to the specific instance of SQL Server.

**Method 3:** Look at the first few lines of the Errorlog file for that instance. By default, the error log is located at Program Files\Microsoft SQL `Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG` and `ERRORLOG.n` files. The entries may resemble the following:

```
2011-03-27 22:31:33.50 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)                 Mar 29 2009 10:11:52                 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation                Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: )
```

As you can see, this entry gives all the necessary information about the product, such as version, product level, 64-bit versus 32-bit, the edition of SQL Server, and the OS version on which SQL Server is running.

**Method 4:** Connect to the instance of SQL Server, and then run the following query:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

**Note This query works with any instance of SQL Server 2000 or of a later version**

Comment: I've found Method 4 to be more reliable than Method 1 -- I've had servers which didn't get a service pack installed correctly where Method 1 and Method 4 returned different results, but Method 4 was correct.

Comment: list of serverproperties: [SERVERPROPERTY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 10):

```
declare @sqlVers numeric(4,2)
select @sqlVers = left(cast(serverproperty('productversion') as varchar), 4)
```

Gives 8.00, 9.00, 10.00 and 10.50 for SQL 2000, 2005, 2008 and 2008R2 respectively.

Also, Try the system extended procedure `xp_msver`. You can call this stored procedure like

```
exec master..xp_msver
```

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR

```cmd
SQLCMD -S (LOCAL) -E -V 16 -Q "IF(ISNULL(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion') AS INT),0)<11) RAISERROR('You need SQL 2012 or later!',16,1)"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :ExitFail
```

This uses [SQLCMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) (comes with SQL Server) to connect to the local server instance using Windows auth, throw an error if a version check fails and return the `@@ERROR` as the command line `ERRORLEVEL` if >= 16 (and the second line goes to the `:ExitFail` label if the aforementioned `ERRORLEVEL` is >= 1).

**Watchas, Gotchas & More Info**

For SQL 2000+ you can use the [SERVERPROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql) to determine a lot of this info.

While SQL 2008+ supports the `ProductMajorVersion` & `ProductMinorVersion` properties, `ProductVersion` has been around since 2000 (remembering that if a property is not supported the function returns `NULL`).

If you are interested in earlier versions you can use the `PARSENAME` function to split the `ProductVersion` (remembering the "parts" are numbered right to left i.e. `PARSENAME('a.b.c', 1)` returns `c`).

Also remember that `PARSENAME('a.b.c', 4)` returns `NULL`, because SQL 2005 and earlier only used 3 parts in the version number!

So for SQL 2008+ you can simply use:

```
SELECT
    SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion,
    CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion')  AS INT) AS ProductMajorVersion,
    CAST(SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductMinorVersion') AS INT) AS ProductMinorVersion;
```

For SQL 2000-2005 you can use:

```
SELECT
    SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion,
    CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS SYSNAME), CASE WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') IS NULL THEN 3 ELSE 4 END) AS INT) AS ProductVersion_Major,
    CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS SYSNAME), CASE WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) AS INT) AS ProductVersion_Minor,
    CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS SYSNAME), CASE WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS INT) AS ProductVersion_Revision,
    CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS SYSNAME), CASE WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS INT) AS ProductVersion_Build;
```

*(the `PARSENAME(...,0)` is a hack to improve readability)*

So a check for a SQL 2000+ version would be:

```sql
IF (CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS SYSNAME), CASE WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') IS NULL THEN 3 ELSE 4 END) AS INT) < 10) -- SQL2008
OR (
    (CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS SYSNAME), CASE WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') IS NULL THEN 3 ELSE 4 END) AS INT) = 10) -- SQL2008
AND (CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS SYSNAME), CASE WHEN SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) AS INT) < 5)  -- R2 (this may need to be 50)
   )
    RAISERROR('You need SQL 2008R2 or later!', 16, 1);
```

This is a lot simpler if you're only only interested in SQL 2008+ because `SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion')` returns `NULL` for earlier versions, so you can use:

```sql
IF (ISNULL(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion') AS INT), 0) < 11) -- SQL2012
    RAISERROR('You need SQL 2012 or later!', 16, 1);
```

And you can use the `ProductLevel` and `Edition` (or `EngineEdition`) properties to determine RTM / SP*n* / CTP*n* and Dev / Std / Ent / etc respectively.

```sql
SELECT
    CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS SYSNAME) AS ProductVersion,
    CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS SYSNAME)   AS ProductLevel,
    CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS SYSNAME)        AS Edition,
    CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS INT)      AS EngineEdition;
```

FYI the major [SQL version numbers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/321185/how-to-determine-the-version-edition-and-update-level-of-sql-server-an) are:

- 8 = SQL 2000
- 9 = SQL 2005
- 10 = SQL 2008 (and 10.5 = SQL 2008R2)
- 11 = SQL 2012
- 12 = SQL 2014
- 13 = SQL 2016
- 14 = SQL 2017

And this all works for SQL Azure too!

**EDITED:**
You may also want to check your [DB compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level) since it could be set to a lower compatibility.

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id=DB_ID() AND [compatibility_level] < 110)
    RAISERROR('Database compatibility level must be SQL2008R2 or later (110)!', 16, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: Here is what i have done to find the version]

Here is what i have done to find the version:
just write `SELECT @@version` and it will give you the version.

Answer (score 1):

This is especially good if you plan to migrate to Azure

It gives you a lot of insight if you are searching compatibility issues:

```
SELECT
    @@servername AS 'Server Name'
   ,CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS [IP Address]
   ,d.name AS [Database_Name]
   ,d.compatibility_level
   ,@@version AS 'Version'
   ,CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')) LIKE '8%' THEN 'SQL2000'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')) LIKE '9%' THEN 'SQL2005'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')) LIKE '10.0%' THEN 'SQL2008'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')) LIKE '10.5%' THEN 'SQL2008 R2'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')) LIKE '11%' THEN 'SQL2012'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')) LIKE '12%' THEN 'SQL2014'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')) LIKE '13%' THEN 'SQL2016'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')) LIKE '14%' THEN 'SQL2017'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')) LIKE '15%' THEN 'SQL2019'
        ELSE 'unknown'
    END AS SQL_Server_Version,
   d.collation_name
   ,(SUM(CAST(mf.size AS BIGINT)) * 8 / 1024) / 1024 AS Size_GBs
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.databases d
    ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE d.database_id > 4 -- Skip system databases
GROUP BY d.name
        ,d.compatibility_level
        ,d.collation_name
ORDER BY d.name
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select charindex(  'Express',@@version)
```

if this value is 0  is not a express edition