# SQL CLR conditional compilation based on SQL Server version

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, msbuild, sqlclr

I'm been using Visual Studio conditional compilation based on the .Net Framework for many of my projects.

But now I'm encountering a need to conditionally compile in a Visual Studio SQL CLR project based on the selected target SQL Server version.

Is there a way to do that?  I need a way to optionally include in the compiled DLL certain .sql files (stored procedures) and C# .cs files (SQL CLR stored procedures)

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

I found a solution for the .cs portion of the SQLCLR project.  I followed the same steps for detecting .Net Framework as per this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526/detect-target-framework-version-at-compile-time)
and then added to the VersionSpecificSymbols.Common.prop file lines like these:

> <DefineConstants Condition="$(DSP.Contains('100'))  ==
>   True">$(DefineConstants);SQL2008</DefineConstants>

I'm still looking for a way to "filter out" stored procedures based on SQL Server version

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no additional answers provided, I'm including my partial solution for the .cs portion of the SQLCLR project:

I followed the same steps for detecting .Net Framework as per this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526/detect-target-framework-version-at-compile-time)
and then added to the VersionSpecificSymbols.Common.prop file lines like these:

> <DefineConstants Condition="$(DSP.Contains('100'))  ==
>   True">$(DefineConstants);SQL2008</DefineConstants>
>
> <DefineConstants Condition="$(DSP.Contains('110'))  ==
>   True">$(DefineConstants);SQL2012</DefineConstants>
>
> <DefineConstants Condition="$(DSP.Contains('120'))  ==
>   True">$(DefineConstants);SQL2014</DefineConstants>
>
> <DefineConstants Condition="$(DSP.Contains('130'))  ==
>   True">$(DefineConstants);SQL2016</DefineConstants>

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do that?

To my knowledge, I am afraid you could not do that. As we know, there is a few ways to get the version of SQL Server:

[How to check SQL Server version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351674/how-to-check-sql-server-version)

But we could not get SQL Server version from the project file `.sqlproj` via MSBuild. So we could not use the condition for the `.sql` files (stored procedures) and C# `.cs` files (SQL CLR stored procedures) directly, like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="SqlStoredProcedure1.cs" Condition=" '$(sqlversion)' == 'sql server 2012' " />
  </ItemGroup>
```

As a workaround, you can define a new configuration:

[image]

For example, SqlServer2012, then set this condition to the `.sql` files (stored procedures) and C# `.cs` files (SQL CLR stored procedures):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Build Include="Procedure1.sql" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'SqlServer2012' "/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="SqlStoredProcedure1.cs" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'SqlServer2012' " />
  </ItemGroup>
```

In this case, those two file only included when you configuration is selected to SqlServer2012.

Note: The limitation of this approach is that you need to know SQL Server version in advance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just edited my question with a partial solution, but your idea for using different configurations is something I did not consider.  The only problem I see is the need to specify the .sql files with each configuration.  I was hoping more for a pre-deployment script action.

Comment: @SQLHTTP, That is OK, you can share your solution with a answer and mark it, so it is more easily for other communities to found the solution.